# How to customize jsonapi-serializer caching namespace - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, jsonapi-serialize

In my rails application I have `categories` which are classified based on `location`. I want to cache these categories on serializer level by using `jsonapi-serializer`'s caching method `cache_options store: Rails.cache, namespace: 'jsonapi-serializer', expires_in: 3.hours`. The issue here is that when I call it for the first time to retrieve categories in `City A` for example then later try to retrieve categories from `City B` it will still show `City A`'s data. What I'm trying to do now is to pass `city` to serializer then add it to `namespace` using something like this `namespace: "jsonapi-serializer/categories/#{:city}"` in order to differentiate between them but I'm not able to find a way to do so yet.

Currently I have this block of code to retrieve `categories` based on location then serialize and render a json

```
      category = Category.active_categories(headers['User-Location'])

      unless category.empty?
        generic_category = Category.all_category
        categories = generic_category, category
        render CategorySerializer.new(categories.flatten, { params: { user_location: headers['User-Location'] } })
      end
```

While `Category.active_categories` and `Category.all_category` are caching the queries as below:

`active_categories:`

```
def self.active_categories(user_location)
  Rails.cache.fetch("active_categories/#{user_location}", expires_in: 3.hours) do
    Category.where(status: 'active')
            .joins(:sellers).where(sellers: { status: 'active', is_validated: true })
            .joins(sellers: :cities).where(cities: { name_en: user_location })
            .joins(sellers: :products).where(products: { status: 'available' })
            .where.not(products: { quantity: 0 }).with_attached_cover
            .order(featured: :desc).uniq.to_a
  end
end
```

`all_category:`

```
def self.all_category
Rails.cache.fetch('all_category', expires_in: 24.hours) do
  Category.where(name_en: 'All').with_attached_cover.first
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution already. Just override the caching method as the example below:

```
require 'active_support/cache'

class MySerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer

  cache_options(store: Rails.cache, namespace: 'jsonapi-serializer', expires_in: 3.hours)

  def self.record_cache_options(options, fieldset, include_list, params)
    return super(options, fieldset, include_list, params) if params[:user_location].blank?
    opts = options.dup
    opts[:namespace] += ':' + params[:user_location]
    opts
  end
end
```